# How to read generated properties file in Spring Boot integration test?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-test

In a Spring Boot web application, I use the `git-commit-id-plugin` Maven plugin to generate a file named `git.properties`, containing all the git commit information, e.g:

```
git.commit.id=35ca97298544d4ee6f8a5392211ebaa0d9bdafeb
```

This file is generated  directly in the `target/classes` repository. So it's included in the classpath. At runtime the file is loaded via an annotation on my main application class :

```
@PropertySource({"git.properties"})
```

I can then use expressions in my beans to get the value of the properties contained in the `git.properties` file :

```
@Value("${git.commit.id}")
private String gitCommitIdFull; // will contain "35ca97298544d4ee6f8a5392211ebaa0d9bdafeb"
```

It all works very well when running the app normally.

But I am now trying to run some integration tests that are run with :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SampleSearchDAOTest {
    //tests here...
}
```

I get the following exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
(...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
Failed to parse configuration class [ch.cscf.mds.MdsApiApplication]; 
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/git.properties]
```

Obviously, the way the tests are run, they seem to not use `target/classes` as the base for the classpath.

What does it use ? How can I make the runtime for these tests aware of the `target/classes/git.properties` file ?

I tried to generate the `git.properties` file into the `src/main/resources` directory instead of the `target/classes` repository. I still have the same error.

Comment: `@PropertySource({"classpath:git.properties"})` perhaps.

Comment: Excellent! It works. Can you put is as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: And some explanation of why it works also would be nice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test runner by default looks for resources relative to the test folder. For example when the `git.properties` file would have been present in `src/test/resources`, then it should also work.

`@PropertySource({"classpath:git.properties"})` tells to look for sources from the entire classpath.